# Major Difference in 2D kernel Density Plots: Seaborn and R

Tags: python, r, seaborn, kernel-density

I am trying to plot data using the 2D kernel density plot of Seaborn's jointplot function (using statsmodels' KDEMultivariate function to calculate a data-driven bandwidth). I've plotted a 2D kernel density in R using the same data and the result looks very good (using the 'ks' package), while the Seaborn plot looks very very different.

I am using the same exact data and the same exact bandwidth for each (taking the bandwidth given by KDEMultivariant and passing that to the R method).

Here is the input.csv data used: https://app.box.com/s/ot7d36t44wrr85pusp5657pc1w2kf5hj

Below are the code used in each and output images from each.

Python / Seaborn:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import statsmodels.api as sm
data = pd.read_csv("input.csv", dtype={'x': float, 'y': float}, skiprows=0)
bw_ml_x = sm.nonparametric.KDEMultivariate(data=data['x'], var_type='c', bw='cv_ml')
bw_ml_y = sm.nonparametric.KDEMultivariate(data=data['y'], var_type='c', bw='cv_ml')        

g = sns.jointplot(x='x', y='y', data=data, kind="kde", stat_func=None, bw=[bw_ml_x.bw, bw_ml_y.bw])

g.plot_joint(plt.scatter, c="w")
g.ax_joint.collections[0].set_alpha(0)

sns.plt.show()
```

Img for Seaborn plot:

[image]

The bandwidth given by bw_ml_x.bw and bw_ml_y.bw is placed in a 2 x 2 R matrix H, where H[1,1] = bw_ml_x.bw, H[2,2] = bw_ml.y.bw, and other values set to zero.

R:

```
library(ks)
fhat <- kde(x=as.data.frame(data[1], data[2]), H=H)
plot(fhat, display="filled.contour2", cont=seq(10,90,by=10))
```

Img for R plot:

[image]

Comment: Using simple normally distributed random data I can't reproduce any surprising behavior by `jointplot` when specifying the bandwidth. I think you need to either post your dataset or find a way to generate some random data that reproduces the problem on your end.

Comment: With that said, I'm not sure that a gaussian KDE is the best model  for your data anyway. It looks quite obviously not gaussian.

Comment: @mwaskom added input.csv file to make the results reproducible.

Comment: Strange, compared to the [API](http://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/_images/seaborn-jointplot-4.png) your seaborn output seems wrong.

Comment: Thanks for these snippets; I was looking for 2d KDE libraries, and here they are!

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your Seaborn/Python plot, many of the points cluster along the (0,n) region and the (1,1) region of your space, just as the KDE of the R plot shows. This indicates that Seaborn and R are looking at the same data; we simply need to reformulate the call to the `kde` in Seaborn in order to visualize the KDE gradients.

If you modify your Python call to match the [documentation](https://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/tutorial/distributions.html) for `Kernel Density Estimation` in Seaborn you'll get a proper 2d-kdf out of Python:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import statsmodels.api as sm
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

data = pd.read_csv("input.csv", dtype={'x': float, 'y': float}, skiprows=0)
bw_ml_x = sm.nonparametric.KDEMultivariate(data=data['x'], var_type='c', bw='cv_ml')
bw_ml_y = sm.nonparametric.KDEMultivariate(data=data['y'], var_type='c', bw='cv_ml')        

g = sns.jointplot(x='x', y='y', data=data, kind="kde")

g.plot_joint(plt.scatter, c="w")
g.ax_joint.collections[0].set_alpha(0)

sns.plt.show()
```

[image]

This accords with the R plot (though the kernel estimators seem to be slightly different, which would account for the variation in gradients between the plots):

[image]